# Why does @font-face doesnt work when I define it correctly?

Tags: html, css, fonts

This is my code for @font-face

```css
@font-face {
  font-family: "NotesEsa-Bold";
  src: url("C:\Users\test\Desktop\Webpage\Fonts\NotesEsaBol.ttf") format("truetype"); /* Safari, Android, iOS */
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}
```

When I use font-family to define the font I added it doesnt work . I use chrome.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you are properly importing the file ?
If you copy the url in your browser, does it point to something or a 404 ?
I am asking, because you posted this in your code `src: url("C:\Users\test\Desktop\Webpage\Fonts\NotesEsaBol.ttf")` and a `d` is missing before the `.ttf`

If this is not the problem, please make sure you are calling the font-family the exact same way you defined it (with or without quotes).

Comment: The file name is ok, its NotesEsaBol . I defined it without quotes .

Comment: 1. If you defined it without quotes (not like what you pasted tho), please verify you're calling it without quotes as well.

2. Please make sure the font-face is defined before you're trying to call it in your code.

3. Finally, please try to use a relative path in your `url('...')` as calling it with an absolute (file protocol) url might cause trouble.

Comment: @AlexCataT _“The file name is ok”_ — That wasn’t the question. Use the [browser console (dev tools)](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/q/8525) (hit `F12`) and read any errors. The dev tools provide a **Network** tab. Please confirm: Is the resource _found_ (e.g. HTTP 200 response)? If not, which _actual URL_ is requested?